# translateY() triggered when hovered from point of origin

Tags: css, hover

is it possible not to trigger the animation indefinitely when you move the cursor at the bottom of the button?

here's how it looks like -- [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwdHW.gif) and [codepen](https://codepen.io/jaeyson/pen/GwwJbm)

```css
.container {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.container .here {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background: darkgreen;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  transition: all .1s;
}

.container .here:hover {
  transform: translateY(-1.5rem) scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="here">hover here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to add `position: absolute;` to `.here`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the button bigger at the bottom by adding a pseudo element and you will avoid the flicker:

```css
.container {
  padding: 1rem;
}

.container .here {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background: darkgreen;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  transition: all .1s;
  position:relative;
}
.container .here:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}

.container .here:hover {
  transform: translateY(-1.5rem) scale(1.5);
}
.container .here:hover:before {
  height:1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="here">hover here</div>
</div>
```